# Weird behaviour of map and max in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
var a = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ];
_.map( a, _.max );
// gives [3, -Infinity, -Infinity]
```

I have tested it on my Chrome browser, on the lodash site.

Shouldn't the code above return [3, 6, 9]?

I can get the correct result with forEach:

```
var a = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ];
var result = [];
_.forEach( a, function(arr) { result.push(_.max(arr)); } );
```

Answer (score 5):

### Overall conclusion

I've opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/379

**Thanks to [jdalton](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/commit/db82244f56e71000659a1a2a2c8b687ba647d304), the issue is now fixed.** Sample: → [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwMsG/3/)

### Details (why is the result 'weird'?)

I have never worked with Lodash in detail, but here are my researches:

> Retrieves the maximum value of a collection. If the collection is empty or falsey `-Infinity` is returned.
>   — [Lodash Documentation: _.max()](http://lodash.com/docs#max)

Testing `_.max()` with each group invidually worked perfectly:

```
_.max([1,2,3]);  // 3
_.max([4,5,6]);  // 6
_.max([7,8,9]);  // 9
```

Now, I tried calling `_.max()` manually in the callback function of `_.map()`:

```
var a = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ];
alert(_.map( a, function(val) {
    return _.max(val);
}));
```

Works fine! So where is the difference between that and supplying `_.max()` as the second parameter?

`_.map()` actually sends 3 parameters to the callback function:

> (value, index|key, collection).
>   — [Lodash Documentation: _.map()](http://lodash.com/docs#map)

Consider the second parameter of `_.max()` now:

> 2.[callback=identity] (Function|Object|string): The function called per iteration. If a property name or object is provided it will be
>   used to create a ".pluck" or ".where" style callback, respectively.
>   — [Lodash Documentation: _.max()](http://lodash.com/docs#max)

**Conclusion:** `_.max()` gets also passed the second and third parameter supplied by `_.map()`. The second parameter is important here! Passing truthy values (e.g. integers != 0) for it lets the function return `-Infinity`.

Test cases ([→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwMsG/1/)):

```
alert(_.max([1,2,3], 0)); // 3
alert(_.max([1,2,3], 1)); // -Infinity
alert(_.max([1,2,3], 2)); // -Infinity
```

That is coming from the boolean checks performed in the source code:
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/f0f7eee963966516490eb11232c9e9b4c6d0cc6c/dist/lodash.js#L3431

Because `callback` (the second parameter) is a truthy value, we will directly jump into the *else* branch. There, `callback` is reassigned as the following (the ternary operation will also take the *else* branch):

```
lodash.createCallback(callback, thisArg, 3);
```

`createCallback()` is defined [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/f0f7eee963966516490eb11232c9e9b4c6d0cc6c/dist/lodash.js#L5168).
It returns the following function for our specific input parameters (these are `1, null, 3`, see `_.max()` for details):

```
return function(object) {
  return object[func];
};
```

Let's say, we save that in a variable called `callback` ([→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwMsG/2/)):

```
var callback = _.createCallback(1, null, 3);
```

Calling that function with `object = 1` (or 2, 3 or 6, etc.) results in `undefined` (that's pretty obvious).

Going back to `_.max()`, we see that there is a loop which compares the *current* value (from the callback function) to the initial/last value, and that is `-Infinity` as set at the beginning of the function.

`undefined > -Infinity` never results in *true*, so `-Infinity` will stay the 'maximum' value.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! I wasn't sure whether it's a bug or a feature, so I wanted to make sure before I raise this issue on lodash github.

Comment: @TPJ You're welcome. The bug got fixed by jdalton yesterday: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/379